# Mistake in a Proof of Linear Independence

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the set of monomials $B_n = (x^0,x^1, ... ,x^n)$ and I have to prove $B_n$ is a basis for $\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{R}^n$ (the set of all polynomials of order $n$ or less with real coefficients). The proof that $B_n$ spans went fine and this is what I wrote for linear independence.

Definition of linear independence: $$\lambda_0\cdot x^0 + \lambda_1\cdot x^1 + ... +\ \lambda_n\cdot x^n = 0 \implies \lambda_i= 0\ \forall\ i.$$

Then, $$\lambda_0\cdot x^0 + \lambda_1\cdot x^1 + ... +\ \lambda_n\cdot x^n = 0\cdot x^0 + 0\cdot x^1 + ... +\ 0\cdot x^n$$

I discussed the next step with my TA and he said it is wrong but I didn't fully understand why:

$$\lambda_0\cdot x^0 = 0\cdot x^0,$$ $$\lambda_1\cdot x^1 = 0\cdot x^1,$$ $$\vdots$$ $$\lambda_n\cdot x^n = 0\cdot x^n$$

For this to be true for all $x,\ \lambda_i$ must be $0\ \forall\ i$.

My TA used a proof using derivatives which was nice but I was hoping someone could tell me why my proof is wrong (or not wrong).

Thank you!

ANSWER: Thank you again to those who commented and answered! The mistake I was making is that I was using the fact that $x^0$ is linearly independent of $x^1$ and so on which is what allowed me to compare coefficients. Without the assumption that they are independent, I would not have been able to do that.

Comment: If anyone knows how to write "the set of all polynomials of order n or less with real coefficients" in LaTex, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: You seem to have written "the set of all polynomials of order n or less with real coefficients" just fine in your comment :) If you mean a particular mathematical notation for this set - then which one?

Comment: I'm not certain I entirely grasp your question, but for the record, the equating of coefficients rule is linear independence of monomials dressed up. If you're concluding from equating of coefficients, your argument is circular. Doing it with derivatives, or perhaps even the fundamental theorem of algebra, is more the way to go.

Comment: Haha very funny. I just realized how to do it, it's fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for your response Theo! Why is it that we need to know monomials are linearly independent to apply the equating of coefficients rule?

Comment: Because the "equating coefficients " rule is true $because$ the vectors are independent. So, the argument is circular. Why not suppose they are not independent and then invoke the fundamental theorem of algebra?

Answer (score 2):

The step doesn't follow from the equality of both sides. Consider the equation

$$1 \cdot (x-1) + 2 \cdot (x-2) + 1 \cdot (x-3) = 2 \cdot (x-1) + 0 \cdot (x-2) + 2 \cdot (x-3).$$
It is true (for all $x$, even) but we cannot conclude from it that $1\cdot (x-1) = 2\cdot (x-1)$ or any of the other inequalities.

If you want to say "for this to be true for all $x$, $\lambda_i$ must be $0$ for all $i$", your best bet to apply this to your initial equation $$\lambda_0\cdot x^0 + \lambda_1\cdot x^1 + ... +\ \lambda_n\cdot x^n = 0.$$ A nonzero polynomial can have at most $n$ real roots, so if this polynomial is equal to $0$ for all real $x$, it must be the zero polynomial.

(Of course, if you do not know or cannot invoke this fact about polynomials, you'll need another approach.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't quite see how your example relates to the question, if we add (8 - 4x) to both sides, it's just 0 = 0. For the second part, I would rather avoid making that statement on the initial equation (even though I know it's right) because it isn't immediately clear and I want my proof to be very easy to follow.

Comment: I am giving you an example of another true equation where you *can't* conclude that the corresponding components are equal - showing that your approach of concluding that all corresponding components are equal isn't always valid.

Comment: The same logic that you use to say $\lambda_n \cdot x^n = 0 \cdot x^n$ would tell you that $1 \cdot (x-1) = 2\cdot (x-1)$, which is false: this shows that the logic is bad.

Comment: But I am only comparing coefficients of $x^i$ to coefficients of $x^i$

Comment: And I am only comparing coefficients of $x-i$ to coefficients of $x-i$. The reason that your case works and mine doesn't is that the monomials are linearly independent - but that's what you're trying to prove!

Comment: Ok. I get it now, I am using the fact that each term is linearly independent to break apart the equation. You helped a lot, thank you very much for your patience!